# How to get monthly periods between a date range in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have say, start and end date as "6/11/1996" and "3/1/2002" in "mm/dd/yyyy" format respectively.
I need to get all the monthly periods as given below.

```
Start Date      End Date
6/11/1996   -    6/30/1996
7/01/1996   -    7/31/1996
8/01/1996   -    8/31/1996
.
.
.
 Till
2/01/2002    -   2/28/2002
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What about `3/1/2002` - `3/1/2002`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the interval is given by way of two bind variables, `:from_dt` and `:to_dt` (strings in the indicated format):

```
with
     inputs ( f_dt, t_dt ) as (
       select to_date(:from_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date(:to_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
     ),
     ld ( l_day, lvl ) as (
       select add_months(last_day(f_dt), level - 1), level
       from   inputs
       connect by level <= months_between(last_day(t_dt), last_day(f_dt)) + 1
     )
select case when ld.lvl = 1 then i.f_dt else add_months(ld.l_day, -1) + 1 end 
                                                                           as start_date,
       least(i.t_dt, ld.l_day)                                             as end_date
from   inputs i cross join ld
;
```

This assumes that in the original post you did, in fact, mean to have one more interval, from 3/1/2002 to 3/1/2002; and the query deals correctly with the case when the from-date and the to-date are in the same month: if the inputs are 6/11/1996 to 6/21/1996, then the output is exactly that interval.

**Added**: creating column aliases in the declaration of factored subqueries (in the WITH clause), as I have done, requires Oracle 11.2 or above. For earlier versions, it is necessary to write it a little differently, like so:

```
with
         inputs as (
           select to_date(:from_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as f_dt, 
                  to_date(:to_dt  , 'mm/dd/yyyy') as t_dt 
           from   dual
         ),
         ld as (
           select add_months(last_day(f_dt), level - 1) as l_day, level as lvl
           from   inputs    ...............
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Getting unsupported column Aliasing error.Not able to figure out where exactly issue is occurring. My apologies, I am new to Oracle.

Comment: @Alok - What version of Oracle are you on? Column aliasing in the WITH clause, as I used in this solution, is available since version 11.2 (not available in 11.1). To find out: SELECT * FROM V$VERSION. I will edit the post to explain how to modify for Oracle 11.1 and below.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `connect by` query with functions `add_months` and `months_between`:

```
with p as ( select date '1996-06-11' d1, date '2002-03-01' d2 from dual )
select greatest(trunc(add_months(d1, level - 1), 'month'), d1) as d1,
       trunc(add_months(d1, level), 'month') - 1 as d2
  from p connect by level <= months_between(trunc(d2, 'month'), trunc(d1, 'month'))
```

The output is exactly as requested.

Comment: You need to cover the case when the from-date and the to-date are in the same month (like, 1996-06-11 to 1996-06-21). Although perhaps the OP wants an interval from 06-11 to 06-30 in that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    L_min_date DATE := '11-Jun-1996';
    L_max_date DATE := '28-Feb-2002';
    L_number_of_months NUMBER := 0;
    L_new_date DATE := NULL;

BEGIN
    L_number_of_months := MONTHS_BETWEEN(L_max_date, L_min_date);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start_Date       End_Date');
    FOR i IN 1..L_number_of_months
    LOOP
        SELECT (ADD_MONTHS(L_min_date, 1) - 1) INTO L_new_date FROM dual;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_min_date || '   -   ' || L_new_date);
        L_min_date := L_new_date + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Something like above can help.