# Generate monthly periods between a date range in Oracle PL/SQL for each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the same problem like in [How to get monthly periods between a date range in Oracle PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101315/how-to-get-monthly-periods-between-a-date-range-in-oracle-pl-sql). But I need generate all monthly periods between each group's date range. How can I modified the decision above?

As result I expect something like this:
If date range of group A is (01/01/2023-03/10/2023), date range of group B is (01/05/2023-05/12/2023)

```
 Group      Start            End
A   -    01/01/2023   -   01/31/2023
A   -    02/01/2023   -   02/28/2023
A   -    03/01/2023   -   03/10/2023

B   -    01/05/2023   -   01/31/2023
B   -    02/01/2023   -   02/28/2023
B   -    03/01/2023   -   03/31/2023
B   -    04/01/2023   -   04/30/2023
B   -    05/01/2023   -   05/12/2023
```

Comment: You should be able to work this out yourself - hint: `trunc(<date>, 'mm')` truncates the specified date to the start of the month. Give it a go, and if you get stuck edit your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: I am very new in pl sql, so I cant' understand how level operation works in group

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dynamically records for each month between range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926912/how-to-create-dynamically-records-for-each-month-between-range-of-dates)

Answer (score 1):

This is a *row generator* technique problem; `case` expression is used to distinguish the first and the last date in the whole period. Something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with ranges (grp, range_From, range_to) as
  2    (select 'A', date '2023-01-01', date '2023-03-10' from dual union all
  3     select 'B', date '2023-01-05', date '2023-05-12' from dual
  4    ),
```

Query begins here; `temp` CTE helps in making the *main* query simpler because it calculates months between range dates. It can be done without it, but query is then more complex than it should be (in my opinion):

```
  5  temp as
  6    (select grp,
  7       range_from,
  8       range_to,
  9       months_between(trunc(range_to, 'mm'), trunc(range_From, 'mm')) + 1 mon_bet
 10     from ranges
 11    )
 12  select grp,
 13    case when column_value = 1 then range_from
 14         else trunc(add_months(range_from, column_value - 1), 'mm')
 15    end start_date,
 16    --
 17    case when column_value = mon_bet then range_to
 18         else last_day(add_months(range_from, column_value - 1))
 19    end end_date
 20  from temp cross join
 21    table(cast(multiset(Select level from dual
 22                        connect by level <= mon_bet
 23                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 24  order by grp, start_date;

G START_DATE END_DATE
- ---------- ----------
A 01/01/2023 01/31/2023
A 02/01/2023 02/28/2023
A 03/01/2023 03/10/2023
B 01/05/2023 01/31/2023
B 02/01/2023 02/28/2023
B 03/01/2023 03/31/2023
B 04/01/2023 04/30/2023
B 05/01/2023 05/12/2023

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive query and the `ADD_MONTHS` function to repeatedly add one month:

```sql
WITH months (id, dt_from, dt_to, dt_end) AS (
  SELECT id,
         dt_from,
         ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt_from, 'MM'), 1),
         dt_to
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         dt_to,
         ADD_MONTHS(dt_to, 1),
         dt_end
  FROM   months
  WHERE  dt_to < dt_end
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT id,
       dt_from,
       LEAST(dt_to - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, dt_end) AS dt_to
FROM   months;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, dt_from, dt_to) AS
SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-03-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-01-05', DATE '2023-05-12' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DT_FROM | DT_TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-31 23:59:59 |
| A | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-02-28 23:59:59 |
| A | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-10 00:00:00 |
| B | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 2023-01-31 23:59:59 |
| B | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2023-02-28 23:59:59 |
| B | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-31 23:59:59 |
| B | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-04-30 23:59:59 |
| B | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-12 00:00:00 |

*Note: In Oracle, a `DATE` always has a time component (your client application may default to only showing the date, and not time, components but that does not mean that they do not exist; only that they aren't being shown).*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5RIAqJf_)

Answer (score 0):

I've understand, that it's need use only `group by` after `connect by level`. All levels will be correct automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest also to analyze the following example:

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/A0RbUvJh

```sql
select t.id
      ,greatest(t.dt_from, trunc   (add_months(t.dt_from,n-1),'mm')) dt_from
      ,least   (t.dt_to  , last_day(add_months(t.dt_from,n-1))) as dt_to
from table_name t
    ,xmltable(
        '0 to xs:integer($M)' 
        passing floor(months_between(dt_to,dt_from)) as M
        columns n for ordinality
    )
```

Short explanation:

- we can use `xmltable('a to b')` as a simple generator, for example:

```sql
SQL> select * from xmltable('3 to 10' columns x for ordinality, y int path '.');

         X          Y
---------- ----------
         1          3
         2          4
         3          5
         4          6
         5          7
         6          8
         7          9
         8         10

8 rows selected.
```

- function `greatest` returns the greatest of a list of one or more expressions, for example, `greatest(3,4,2,6)` returns 6. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GREATEST.html
- function `least` is a similar function: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LEAST.html
- `MONTHS_BETWEEN(date1,date2)` returns number of months between dates date1 and date2: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MONTHS_BETWEEN.html
- `LAST_DAY(date)` returns the date of the last day of the month that contains date: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST_DAY.html
- `ADD_MONTHS(date,integer)` returns the date date plus integer months: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html
- `TRUNC(date,'mm')` returns the first day of month: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html